# uploading mp4 with PHP

Tags: php, html

Hello guyys i am tring to upload mp4 file with php from 2 days... I started to hate php :D I changed the post settings in php.ini... My codes are:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("mp4","ogg","webm");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a MP4, OGG, or WEBM formats...";
      }

      if($file_size > 800000000){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 800 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"videos/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }


?>
```

When i am trying to upload any image file, the code is working correcty, displaying correct error message, but when i am trying to upload mp4 file, its no showing any erros, i cheked the "videos" folder, nothing inside.  Note: I am working on localhost..

Comment: Are the files bigger than your PHP is allowed to upload? Are you sure your files are *exactly* 800M?

Comment: Yes ofcourse i cheked 100times, my mp4 file is 102 MB, thanks for answer

Comment: @HalidKyazim I would try uploading a smaller mp4 file and see if that works. On a side note: When you check `if($file_size > 800000000)` the error message should say "The file size is too large, must be less than 800MBs" and not "exactly."

Comment: Yes i tryed to upload smaller file (100MB)  still same .. :)

Comment: The `end()` requres only a **variable**

Comment: @Deadooshka What u mean, be clear ? i dont have "end()" function.. thanks for anwer...

Comment: Did the `echo 'success';`  got called? `move_uploaded_file()` can also fail if the directory `!is_writable()` by the webserver.

Comment: I did a file upload for a job, it works fine, its seems to be similar, the only difference is that I do not use restraints.

Comment: @frz3993 nope! "Succes" is did'nt called just blank, and the "videos" folder also, blank

Comment: @JoseMarques could you exlpain more aboaut the  differece?, thnaks for reply

Comment: @HalidKyazim: Did you check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, both?

Comment: Can you please edit your post and show your HTML form that you use to send the upload. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my partial code for a file upload. It works for all types of files.
MY PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
        $target_dir = $basedir."/".$dir;
        $target_file_name = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $target_file = $target_dir."/".$target_file_name;
        $uploadOk = 1;
        if (file_exists($target_file)) 
        {
            $text = "Sorry, item already exists.";
            $bulean = 1;
            alert($text);
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        if ($uploadOk == 0) 
        {
            $text = "Sorry, your item was not uploaded.";
            $bulean = 1;
            alert($text);
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
            {
                $text = "The item ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                $bulean = 1;
                alert($text);
            }
            else 
            {
                $text = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your item.";
                $bulean = 1;
                alert($text);
            }
        }
```

Html

```
<form action="form_upload.php?dir=<?php echo $dir;?>"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
...
Select data to upload:
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="submit">
```

Comment: Dude how you can accept all type of files, trolls will send u virus... also your code is too long for acceptiog all type of files...

Comment: First I did this work, as learning work. when I do projects, I use restrictions. Second, I did not make any restriction of type or size of files, The code that you see, is only to know if the file was uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes to your code. try this. working absolutely fine now. 
Tested locally

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST"  action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];

//print_r($_FILES['file']['name']); 

  $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


      //$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

      $expensions= array("mp4","ogg","webm");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a MP4, OGG, or WEBM formats...";
      }

      if($file_size > 800000000){
         $errors[]='File size must be excately 800 MB';
      }
//print_r($file_tmp); exit;
      if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"videos/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Important: *Do not* let the user specify the file name. There's easy ways around the file extension checks if you do that, allowing the user to execute arbitrary code on your server (and potentially overwrite config files etc). Consider things like `evil.php.mp3` which some webservers will execute as a PHP script (it's particularly common with .php.jpg, for example).

Comment: Muhammad thank you verry much its working fine, where was the mistake ? Luke Briggs how to fix this ? thank you for reply

Comment: have changed this line only:
  $file_ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

Comment: if this is working fine for you please accept it as answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you solve your problem with some links below:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+upload+large+file

When I was performing my first upload code with PHP, I made the amateur error of ignoring the documentation of what needed to be changed in the apache2 settings (I think at that time there was only apache2 for PHP).

What you need to understand is that you are sending a file larger than allowed in your settings, so PHP is not able to perform the operation and your POST is rendered blank.

You need to change your php.ini according to the specifications and import an upload limit on your validations on the client as well (before uploading).